# Read data from GitHub and split line into several rows in R

Tags: r

I have this text file stored on GitHub:

https://github.com/lopezbec/COVID19_Tweets_Dataset/blob/master/Coronavirus%20Tweets_ID/coronavirus_2020_01_22.txt

That contains a unique large line with values saved as a list (values separated as `["123", "1234", ...]`).

I would like to split the values and write each value on one line.

I tried to figure this out but my code seems not to be working.

```
my_data <- scan (file=input, what = character())
row <- strsplit(my_data, ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably close to what you want.

Notice that you can download directly from the raw.github content into a `data.frame` using `readr::read_tsv()`. The key here is to give a column name to the header (I chose `x`).
We then split that like you were aiming to (using `,` instead of just `,`) and do some cleaning for the `[]` (notice escaping).

```
df <- readr::read_tsv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lopezbec/COVID19_Tweets_Dataset/master/Coronavirus%20Tweets_ID/coronavirus_2020_01_22.txt", col_names = "x")

vec <- unlist(strsplit(df$x, ", "))
head(vec)
tail(vec)
vec <- gsub(x = vec, pattern = "\\[|\\]", replacement = "") 

# optional
vec <- as.numeric(vec)
write.table(vec, "filename.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

`myfile.txt` is your data file.

```
# read csv file as data frame
df <- read.table(file = "myfile.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# remove square brackets and convert character to numeric class
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(x = x, pattern = "\\[|\\]", replacement = "")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using just `scan` and `gsub`:

```r
my_data <- scan("coronavirus_2020_01_22.txt", what = character())
data_vec <- gsub("(,|\\[|\\])", "",  my_data)
```